# Simple python login system not working

Tags: python, login

This is a simple login system, but when using it the USER or nickname doesn't 
work it will login with any username i put in but PASS or password works fine. (I tried googling nothing)

Here's my code:

```
USER = "Haze"
PASS = "Myinternet202"

nickname = raw_input("Nickname: ")
if nickname == "%s" % (USER):
    credentials = True
else:
    credentials = False
password = raw_input("Password: ")
if password == "%s" % (PASS):
    credentials = True
else:
    credentials = False

if credentials == False:
    print '----------------------------------------'
    print '-          INVALID CREDENTIALS         -'
    print '----------------------------------------'
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.exit(1)

if credentials == True: 
    print 'Type "HELP" For A List Of Commands'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're effectively ignoring the setting of credentials from the "nickname" check, because it's overwritten when you check for password.

Try:

- Check if "credentials == True" before (or ANDed with) the password check.
- OR, use two credentials variables (e.g. credentialsUser, credentialsPwd), so you can do two if-checks and output a specific message (or log for sys-admin) "username unknown" or "incorrect password".

Comment: I managed to get it working :)

Comment: Hope my answer helped.  :)